# Express Middleware - call cycle

Tags: node.js, express

```
module.exports = errorHandler;

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (typeof (err) === 'string') {
        // custom application error
        return res.status(400).json({ error: err });
    }

    if(err.name === 'Unauthorized') {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: err.message })
    }

    // default to 500 server error
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
}
```

```
// register routes
app.use('', require('./controllers/view.controller'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./controllers/auth.controller'))
app.use('/api/games', require('./controllers/game.controller'))
app.use('/api/bets', require('./controllers/bet.controller'))
app.use('/api/coupons', require('./controllers/coupon.controller'))
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/user.controller'))

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);
```

Is this error handler considered express middleware or an express route?
Is express middleware called before or after the request cycle? Or does it depend on when in the cycle its called? For example this errorHandler is registered after the routes, therefore its called after the request cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Such `errorHandler` is a special type of Express middleware which is only called when an error happened (typically by a middleware calling `next(err)` with a non-null parameter). You can tell it's an error middleware by the number of arguments declared: 4 instead of usual 2 or 3.

So it does not matter where you add it, before or after the normal route handlers (though they are usually defined last). But in relation to each other, on every request cycle, error middlewares do follow the order they are added; the first one added is always called first by Express in the error handling chain.